# タグ batch-file について

Tags: 討議, タグ

[batch-file](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) というタグがあります。Wikiはまだありませんが、タグ名からすると一般的なバッチ処理を対象としていそうですが、実際に使われている質問は現在３件ともWindowsの .BAT 形式についてです。これらの質問であれば bat-file の方が適切かなと思いました。
このような場合はどう扱うのが適切でしょうか？ …また私には権限が足りないかもしれないのでどなたか対応をお願いしたいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

英語版StackOverflowでも`batch-flie`タグは[Windows/DOSのバッチフィル](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info)を指しています。なお、`bat-file`タグは存在しませんでした。

日本固有の事情でもない限りは、本家と揃えておいた方が便利かとおもいますので、現状維持で良いと考えます。

Answer (score 2):

これは「バッチ処理」と勘違いされないかというのは、先日、 [sh](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sh) タグの Wiki を編集をするときに、私も気になりました。

`bat-file` を別に作るのもいいですが、別に `batch-processing` を作成してもいいと思います。このサイトでは、[タグの別名](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)（シノニム / エイリアス）を付けることができますので、 `batch-file` を残す場合、別名として `bat-file` タグを追加することになると思います。

参考までに、 stackoverflow.com では、 [batch-file](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) タグに対して、　"windows-batch", "batch-files", "winbatch", "dos-batch", "bat", ".bat", "batch", "batch-script" がタグシノニムとして登録されています。 ユーザベースで申請を行うには、 該当タグを含む質問でスコア稼がないといけないようですが、Meta 質問でタグ申請をしてそれが必要とされれば (例えば +7 ぐらい集まって、モデレータが呼び出される等で） タグの追加は叶うと思います。

あとは、 「Wiki 抜粋」 でヒントを出すことでもいいと思います。タグの利用方法に Windows BAT ファイルが含まれるということを明記すれば、タグを入力時 <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> と入力したところで候補と説明ポップアップすることになり間違えなくなると... と思いましたので、 [batch-file](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) の抜粋と [Wiki ページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info)に に基本的な部分を記述しておきました。足りないところ、おかしなところがあれば修正してください。（翻訳しただけなので必要に応じてがっつり変えるなり削除するなりしてください。）